# Is there any way to reference $this inside an association's conditions?

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

Let's say I have a Screenshot model with a `date` column which defines when the screenshot was taken. I also have a GameVersion model with `start_date` and `end_date` instance methods defining the beginning and end of the given version.

If I want a `screenshots` association for each GameVersion, which returns all screenshots taken between its `start_date()` and `end_date()`, can I do anything like this?

```
static $has_many = [
    ['screenshots', 'conditions' => ['date >= ? AND date <= ?', $this->start_date(), $this->end_date()]],
];
```

If I try that, I get:

`Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ']'`

In Ruby on Rails, this is accomplished like so:

```
has_many :birthday_events, ->(user) { where starts_on: user.birthday }, class_name: 'Event'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$this` with static members, use `self::` instead.

Comment: That results in `Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ']'` (full line: `static $has_many = [['screenshots', 'conditions' => ['date >= ? AND date <= ?', self::start_date(), self::end_date()]]];`). To clarify, `start_date()` and `end_date()` are instance methods, not static/class methods.

Comment: @TonyFox which version of php? I suggest you to use regular syntax, to avoid issues. or maybe you forgot to close semicolon somewhere

Comment: 5.4.7, and what part of the code isn't regular syntax? Unless you mean array() instead of [], which I'll try.

Comment: no its fine for this version, check to see if the syntax issue is above this line, like forgot to close bracket or semicolon because it looks fine

Comment: Can you create associative arrays using []? Try replacing with array() instead of []. See if that fixes it.

Comment: [] works fine in 5.4.7, and using array() resulted in the same thing, except complaining that it was expecting a ) instead of a ]. [Here's the full file](http://pastebin.com/3ugnAgfH), there are no syntax errors and it works fine if I just don't try to use anything fancy like variables in the has_many block. It looks like php-activerecord just doesn't support doing something like that, but I'm hoping there's a workaround.

Comment: Actually, I just realized why this doesn't work. In PHP, "static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed". Now the question is, is there another way to create an association in php-activerecord that DOES allow expressions/variables?

Comment: Sorry i dont know php-active record, why does it have to be static

Comment: I don't know how it works internally, but that's just how you create associations: [documentation](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Associations).